# Is there fluent wait in Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I want to wait for an XPath that sometimes appears and sometimes it doesn't. If it appears, then do plan A, and if it doesn't appear in, let's say, 5 seconds, do plan B.

Is this possible? Or should I just use `await page.waitFor(5000)` to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`page.waitForXPath()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.0.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitforxpathxpath-options):

```js
const element = await page.waitForXPath(xpath, {timeout: 5000}).catch(e => void e);
if (element)
    //plan A
else
    //do plan B
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, because when the timeout happens, the process stops and the if never happens.

Comment: @WillyCarrera see my edited answer. you can just wrap it with try/catch

Comment: i'll try this now